# Open Fragment from fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to open a fragment from another one.
I use this code

```
            Fragment newFragment = new TabFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

But it doesn't work. This is error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: simone.biliato.fortitudobasketvedelago, PID: 4166
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00ab (simone.biliato.fortitudobasketvedelago:id/viewpager) for fragment TabFragment{12144aca #1 id=0x7f0d00ab}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Into "transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, newFragment);" what should I specify? Anyother has the same problem?

Comment: The `R.id` you pass in that method call should be the ID for the `ViewGroup` that will hold the `Fragment`, whichever `ViewGroup` you have for that. It really shouldn't be a `ViewPager`.

Comment: You might want to be using `getSupportFragmentManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new NewFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a view inside the fragment with id "viewpager".
Add a ViewGroup (a FrameLayout for example) inside the fragment to be container for the new fragment to be placed.

Comment: This is the xml of TabAcitivty();